# Is there an official list of valid ALPN protocol strings?

Tags: ssl, alpn

Are there official ALPN protocol strings for well-known protocols? I've seen clients and servers that send or expect HTTP/1.1 to be referenced with the ALPN string `http/1.1`, `http1.1`, and `http 1.1`. For example, I work with a proxy that received `http 1.1` for HTTP/1.1 from a client while the proxy expected `http/1.1`, so the proxy rejected the TLS handshake because the protocol was unrecognized. Are one of these officially correct or incorrect? I can't find an RFC that either specifies these explicitly nor, conversely, can I find an RFC that says there is officially no standard. (I might simply be missing it from browsing [RFC 7301](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7301.html).) HTTP/2, on the other hand, seems to always be referenced as `h2`.

Comment: https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-extensiontype-values/tls-extensiontype-values.xhtml#alpn-protocol-ids

Comment: Extending Steffen comment that should be... an answer :-), see point 6 of the RFC you quote. It specifically directs IANA to create the registry to hold all those values, hence that link on their server. Note also the registration type being "Expert Review" which means all values should have been looked at by someone and associated with a specification. It is not free form/open lunch. Yet, of course, neither IETF nor IANA are the protocol police, so on the wire, lots of things can happen.

Comment: But in short and for reference the true version registered is `http/1.1` and hence nothing else should theoretically exists for HTTP version 1.1 inside a TLS handshake.

Comment: Thank you, both , this is helpful. I'll let one of you provide an official answer and I'll accept it.